# Union Query Across Databases

Tags: ms-access, union

I want to run a union query on qry_1 in C:\DB\DB1.mdb and qry_2 in C:\DB\DB2.mdb

All examples I have seen only show how to run a Union Query on query's in the same database, how can you do this when the query's are in different databases?

EDIT ---
Grr, not quite displaying results like I was after.  That shows each entry twice.  Is there a way to only show the entry one time?  For example if qry_1 returns Joe 14, Jack 16, Jimmy 12 and qry_2 returns Joe 22, Jack 48, Jimmy 66 is there a way to SUM those results in the UNION Query?
I tried changing the syntax to a group by like so, but didn't work:

```
Select Name, Count FROM [C:\DB\DB1.mdb].qry_1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Count FROM [C:\DB\DB2.mdb].qry_2
GROUP BY Name, Count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case nothing changed, use:

```
SELECT * FROM [C:\DB\DB1.mdb].qry_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [C:\DB\DB2.mdb].qry_2
```

UPD: To SUM them i would recommend GROUP BY. Let's say we saved upper query as qry_U then try smth like this:

```
SELECT [Name], SUM([Numbers]) FROM [qry_U] GROUP BY [Name]
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.  Please take note of my edit and let me know if access allows for this.